# Get sub-data while displaying with fetch?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on something where a user can create notes.

A note have a id, a owner_id and data.
Actually when the page load I make a basic SELECT query to get all the note of the user and display it with PHP loop and fetch:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, data FROM notes WHERE owner = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["id"]);

[...]

while($stmt->fetch()){
    display_note($note_id, $data);
}
```

The notes table looks like this :

```
Note(id, owner, data)
```

What I am trying to do is to add tags to notes. To do that a created two additional tables :

```
Tags(id, name)
Note_tags(note_id, tag_id)
```

So when a user add a tag, my PHP code looks if the tag name already exist get the id of that tag or create it instead and get back the new created tag id.

Then I add a entry in the `note_tags` table with the note id and the tag id.

The problem is I don't know how to get all the tags of a note while displaying the note one after the other in my fetch loop.

I thought I have to do a SELECT query for each note but I think this is not the best solution. For example, if a user have more than 100 notes, does making 100 queries is a good idea ?

If they are no better solution, so how to do nested queries in PHP ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a multidimensional array.

First, get all notes and tags :

```
SELECT notes.id, data, tag_id, tags.name AS tag_name
FROM notes
LEFT JOIN note_tags ON note_id = tag_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_id
WHERE owner = ?
```

Then iterate over the result to build the array

```
$data = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $data[$row["id"]]["data"] = $row["data"];
    $data[$row["id"]]["tags"][$row["tag_id"]] = $row["tag_name"];
}
```

Now you should have an array that looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "data":"The content of a note",
        "tags": [
            "the name of a tag",
            "the name of an other tag"
        ]
    },
    {
        "data":"The content of an other note",
        "tags": [
            "the name of a tag",
            "the name of an other tag"
        ]
    }
]
```